# jQuery - detect iPhone in-call status bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, web-applications, statusbar

As the title suggests, is there any way in jQuery to detect/determine whether the in-call status bar is visible (hence if the user's in a call) so I can make changes to the GUI of my iOS web app accordingly?

I realize "determine whether the user is in a call" might be impossible from javascript. I'm also aware of the fact that this can be done using Objective C and Phonegap/Cordova plugin. However, this is not the solution I'm looking for.

What I rather search for is a work around that determines this by some other parameters, for instance by measuring the hight of the status bar or `orientation change event` in any way. Any ideas?

PS. Please let me know if you would like to have a look a my so-far fruitless attempts.

Comment: The status bar isn't part of a WebView, so I'd be very surprised if anything about it can be accessed by Javascript.

Comment: Thats absolutely right but as I said, im looking for a way to figure that out in another way. For exempel measuring the canvas size, adding a listener on something similar to onOrientationChange, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, thats how easy it was - just measure the canvas height! Assuming the user uses an iPhone:

```
var biggerStatusBar = false;
var screenHeight = window.screen.height;
var canvasHeight = $(document).height();
if(screenHeight-canvasHeight==40)
biggerStatusBar =true;

alert("in-call status bar active: " + biggerStatusBar);
```

Comment: True, I'll test this thoroughly and come back and revise this if needed.

Comment: For example, I think there is a similar status bar presented when doing turn-by-tune directions, so I'd expect it to have the same effect on the canvas size.

Comment: Yes, I'm very well aware of that and it makes no difference to me. All I want is to be able to adjust the GUI according to the change in canvas size.

Comment: @Johnathan: Then your question title, and in fact the question itself, is a bit misleading, no?  If all you cared about is the canvas size, HOW it changed should be (and, apparently is) irrelevant.